# How to terminate process with Lucene NRT Reader/ Writer gracefully?

Tags: lucene, lucene-nrt

We are using Lucene's near real-time search feature for full-text search in our application. Since commits are costly, say we commit to index after every 10 documents are added (We expect around 150 to 200 documents per hour for indexing). Now, if I want to terminate my process, how do I make sure that all documents in memory are committed to disk before my process is killed? Is there any approach recommended here? Or is my document volume too less to bother about and should I commit on every addition?

Should I track all uncommitted documents? And if process gets killed before they are committed to disk, should I index these uncommitted ones again when the process start up?

Lucene NRT is used in a process that runs embedded Jetty. Is it the right approach to send a shutdown command (invoke some servlet) to jetty and wait till all documents are committed and then terminate using System.exit()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a hook to commit all the buffered documents in the [destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy%28%29) method of your servlet and make sure that the embedded servlet container is shut down before calling System.exit (maybe by adding a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html) to the JVM).

But this is still not perfect. If your process gets killed, all the buffered data will be lost. Another solution is to use soft commits. Soft commits are cheap commits (no fsync is performed) so no data will be lost if your process gets killed (but data could still be lost if the server shuts down unexpectedly).

To sum up:

- shutdown hook

  - best throughput
  - data can be lost if the process gets killed
- soft commit

  - no data will be lost if the process gets killed
  - data may be lost if the server shuts down unexpectedly
- hard commit (default)

  - no data loss at all
  - slow (need to perform a fsync)

Comment: how do you do soft commit in lucene? Can't find any resources when searched on google.

Comment: Sorry, this is a Solr-only feature. I thought it was available in Lucene too, but it is not, meaning you will have to implement it yourself if you want to use it. You can read some doc about it at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages and some technical doc at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2193 (the most recent patch contains a working implementation for soft commits).